# How can I setup my Hyper-V virtual machine to have the convenience features of Windows Sandbox?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-sandbox

The Windows Sandbox (a feature of Windows 10 Pro) provides a temporary virtual machine instance that has these nice convenience features:

- Resizing the Window to automatically adjust the display size/resolution
- Copying and pasting *text* between host and sandbox
- Copying and pasting *files* between host and sandbox

How can I enable the above features in a standard Hyper-V virtual machine?

I've created a guest VM, installed Windows 10 Home, enabled "Enhanced session mode", and enabled "Integration Services > Guest services" but none of these features are working. Is that because my guest is only using the "Home" edition, or is there some other setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

After I posted the question, I decided to upgrade my guest OS to Windows 10 Pro. As soon as I did that, all 3 convenience features I listed above suddenly activated, with no further settings required.

So it appears these features are only supported on Windows 10 Pro guests, and not 10 Home guests.